# How to create znode on a docker compose cluster using "command" in the compose file?

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create a docker-compose file to run zookeeper and solr (3 node cluster - official images). I am trying define a znode in the zookeeper using the "command" attribute in the compose file.

```
command: bash -c "/apache-zookeeper-3.5.8-bin/bin/zkCli.sh -server zoo1:2181 create /solr '' && zkServer.sh start-foreground"
```

The zookeeper node with this command keep on crashing again and again.

My docker compose file is :

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - 'zoo1_data:/data'

  zoo2:
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    container_name: zoo2
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo2
    ports:
      - 2182:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - 'zoo2_data:/data'

  zoo3:
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    container_name: zoo3
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo3
    ports:
      - 2183:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
    command: bash -c "/apache-zookeeper-3.5.8-bin/bin/zkCli.sh -server zoo2:2181 create /solr '' && zkServer.sh start-foreground"
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - 'zoo3_data:/data'
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2

  solr1:
    image: solr:8.3
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8981:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181/solr
    volumes:
      - 'solr1varsolr:/var/solr'
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  solr2:
    image: solr:8.3
    container_name: solr2
    ports:
     - "8982:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181/solr
    volumes:
      - 'solr2varsolr:/var/solr'
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  solr3:
    image: solr:8.3
    container_name: solr3
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181/solr
    volumes:
      - 'solr3varsolr:/var/solr'
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

networks:
  solr:
volumes:
  zoo1_data:
  zoo2_data:
  zoo3_data:
  solr1varsolr:
  solr2varsolr:
  solr3varsolr:
```

From what it appears to me the second part of the command responsible for starting the zookeeper in the container is not getting executed but i cannot figure out why? and also is there any other way to achieve this ?

### Resolved

Found the reason. It was missing "exec" before "zkServer.sh start-foreground" in the command option. Resulting in container being shutdown after execution of command.
thanks @Yoeri Van Nieuwerburg for sample compose file to compare with.

working compose file :

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    container_name: zoo1
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - 'zoo1_data:/data'

  zoo2:
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    container_name: zoo2
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo2
    ports:
      - 2182:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - 'zoo2_data:/data'

  zoo3:
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    container_name: zoo3
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo3
    ports:
      - 2183:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: mntr,conf,ruok
    command: bash -c "/apache-zookeeper-3.5.8-bin/bin/zkCli.sh -server zoo2:2181 create /solr '' && exec zkServer.sh start-foreground"
    networks:
      - solr
    volumes:
      - 'zoo3_data:/data'
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2

  solr1:
    image: solr:8.3
    container_name: solr1
    ports:
     - "8981:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181/solr
    volumes:
      - 'solr1varsolr:/var/solr'
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  solr2:
    image: solr:8.3
    container_name: solr2
    ports:
     - "8982:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181/solr
    volumes:
      - 'solr2varsolr:/var/solr'
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

  solr3:
    image: solr:8.3
    container_name: solr3
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181/solr
    volumes:
      - 'solr3varsolr:/var/solr'
    networks:
      - solr
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3

networks:
  solr:
volumes:
  zoo1_data:
  zoo2_data:
  zoo3_data:
  solr1varsolr:
  solr2varsolr:
  solr3varsolr:
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but I'm not sure why you're trying to "create" the solr directory on the zookeeper instance?
Solr is just an instance, connecting to the zookeeper node, right?
Or do you want to connect multiple systems on your ensemble? If so, I think you should check out [this solr-doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#using-a-chroot), which shows exactly that ("Using a chroot").

Anyways, if you just want to get it up-and-running without using the `/solr` endpoint, here's how one of my zookeeper nodes looks like in my docker-compose (for local development only):

```
zoo3:
    image: library/zookeeper:3.5.7
    container_name: zoo3
    restart: always
    hostname: zoo3
    ports:
      - 8384:8080
    environment:
      TZ: Europe/Paris
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181
    networks:
      - solr
    command: >
      sh -c "ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && 
      echo $TZ > /etc/timezone &&
      sed -i 's/autopurge.purgeInterval=0/autopurge.purgeInterval=1/g' /conf/zoo.cfg  &&
      echo 4lw.commands.whitelist=mntr,conf,ruok >> /conf/zoo.cfg &&
      exec zkServer.sh start-foreground"
```

The only thing you'll have to change in the solr-services, is the url for the zoo3 from `zoo3:2181/solr` to `zoo3:2181`... which is already being used for the other 2 nodes ;)

All the nodes use the same setup (except for the naming and the `ZOO_SERVERS` environment variable of course :) )

Hope this helps, if not, hoping I didn't confuse you ;)

Comment: Hi, I want to share this zookeeper Ensemble for hosting other applications and will also be using it to store shared data. For data to be segregated properly i would need to chroot "/appname" for each application.
i was able to run the compose file without chroot.

Comment: I found the cause by comparing compose file shared by you. Mine was missing "exec" before "zkServer.sh start-foreground" in the command option.
thanks

Comment: Hmmm... oké, I'm starting to feel your pain as I'm trying to get it up and running...
Defining the env. ZK_CHROOT doesn't seem to cut it for clusters :(

Comment: @mr-price, no problem... 
Mind sharing your entire compose-file? :D